# Why do I get the name field is required, while trying to update through api in laravel, it doesn't seem to be taking my inputs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, postman

This is my update function, I'm using postman to test the api,
My url goes: http://localhost:8000/api/userregister/25
25 is the ID of the user I'm trying to update.
I'm sending a PUT request

I get this response:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `name` = ?, `email` = ?, `phone` = ?, `users`.`updated_at` = 2020-02-09 16:39:43 where `id` = 25) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 669



public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    //     'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    //     'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    //     'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    //     'phone' => 'required|string|min:6',
    //     'Age' => 'required|string',
    //     'Blood' => 'string',
    //     'Gender' => 'required|string',
    //     'Height' => 'string',
    //     'Weight' => 'string',
    //     'record' => 'string'
    // ]);

    // if($validator->fails()){
    //         return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
    // }

    $doc = User::find($id);

    if($request->hasFile('picture')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('picture')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    $doc->name = $request->input('name');
      $doc->email = $request->input('email');
      $doc->phone = $request->input('phone');
      if($request->hasFile('picture')){
        $doc->picture = $bannerName;
        }



       $doc->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success',

    ]);

}
```

Comment: Looks like `$request->input('name');` results in `null`. Uncomment the validation to avoid the QueryException.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending `multipart/formdata` in a PUT request it won't work since HTML forms only support GET and POST.

You have two options: 
Either send `Content-Type: application/json` in PUT request

Or

Send a form-data in POST request with an additional field:
`_method : PUT`.

Answer (score 0):

You may fix it by

1. Setting 'name' column to Nullable in your db
2. Making 'name' attr required
3. Simply use `$doc->name = $request->input('name') ?? '';`

Comment: This is does not answer the question or solve the problem. Why should the op change name to nullable what if the system really requires name  ?